# Is there a one-line code that can collects the first element of a tuple of a dict?

Tags: python

For example,

```
my_dict = {'a':(1,2), 'b':(3,4), 'c':(5,6)}
```

I want to get a list of:

```
[1,3,5]
```

Is there a one-line code that can extract the values?  I have to do this way:

```
values = [v[0] for v in list(my_dict.values())]
```

Is there an even better way than this line?

Comment: What does "even better" entail?

Comment: You have a one-liner that does exactly what you want and says exactly what it means. That's not good enough?

Comment: list(my_dict.values()): looks verbose?

Comment: @marlon `list` is redundant here. `[v[0] for v in my_dict.values()]` is valid. You could use tuple unpacking in the loop `[v for _,v in my_dict.values()]`

Comment: `values = [x[0] for x in my_dict.values()]` does the exact same thing without the list cast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A list comprehension is the best way to go both for readability and performance:

```py
[t[0] for t in my_dict.values()]
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you only want the first elements, another option could be to use `zip` and `next`:

```py
out = [*next(zip(*my_dict.values()))]
```

Output:

```py
[1, 3, 5]
```

That said, your version is much more readable and what I would use for myself.

Answer (score 0):

The `next()` solution from @enke is fantastic, but would only work for when you want the first item. Similarly, tuple unpacking would only be feasible if the tuples are relatively small. This solution gives you control over grabbing any element:

```py
>>> from operator import itemgetter as get

>>> [*map(get(0), my_dict.values())]
[1, 3, 5]
```